# how do I use an object file created with Cabal?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have a source file that will only compile with Cabal. It's test code, and in the past (before I complicated my Haskell environment) I would run functions from within ghci. 
I know ghci can use object files to load code, but when I try to do so I get the following error. So what am I missing?

[mlitchard@Boris Boris_Test]$ ghci /home/mlitchard/Boris_Test/dist/build/Boris_Test/Boris_Test-tmp/Main.o

```
GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading object (static) /home/mlitchard/Boris_Test/dist/build/Boris_Test/Boris_Test-tmp/Main.o ... done
final link ... ghc: /home/mlitchard/Boris_Test/dist/build/Boris_Test/Boris_Test-tmp/Main.o: unknown symbol
```

`monadzmcontrolzm0zi3zi1zi3_ControlziMonadziTransziControl_zdfMonadBaseControlIOIO_closure'
linking extra libraries/objects failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify object files manually, GHCi can't tell what the object file depends on, which it would be able to do with `.hs` files, because it has access to the `import ...` lines in that situation.

Therefore, you need to add the object files of all the relevant dependencies manually, in this case by adding `-package monad-control`, when invoking GHCi.